# 3D Touch and UITableViewCell

Tags: swift, ios9, 3dtouch

I added some test `3D Touch` functionality to `UITableViewController` on iPhone 6s. In general it works fine, but I was able to observe some 2 problems, and I am not sure what is happening and how to fix that in a normal way.

1) My cell is selectable, so user can press on it or use "3D Touch". The problem is that when I use "Pop" and "Peek" for `UITableViewCell` it becomes selected and I can not deselect in a normal way using `setSelected:` or `setHighlighted:` methods. I tried to deselect it in different places even in `previewingContext:commitViewController` in `presentViewController` completion. They just do nothing and cells still stay in selected state. I retrieved selected cell by calling `reviewingContext.sourceView` and other temp code which gave me selected cell, but these methods didn't work.

- *So the question is there a normal way to deselect (or better no to select) the cell when user applied "Pop" press on it?*

2) I also noticed that sometimes when I cancel "Pop" gesture and bring cell to initial state (when `previewingContext:viewControllerForLocation` method wasn't even called) my UI just hangs and doesn't respond to touches at all. I need to kill to make it work. It seems very strange, I checked this [Tutorial](http://laurenz.io/2015/10/ios-9-uitableview-how-to-peek-and-pop-in-to-table-cells-with-3d-touch/). It works great, without mentioned issues, but they register delegate not on the cell, but on `UITableView` so "Pop" gesture highlight the whole tableView, but not the cell.

- *Any thoughts and what can be wrong here?*

Here is how I implemented 3D touch in my test `UITableViewController` which conforms to `UIViewControllerPreviewingDelegate`

```
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell
{
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("SomeDemoID",
        forIndexPath: indexPath) as! UITableViewCell

    // Some cell configuration

    if #available(iOS 9.0, *) {
        if traitCollection.forceTouchCapability == .Available {
            self.registerForPreviewingWithDelegate(self, sourceView: cell)
        }
    } else { // Fallback on earlier versions}

    return cell;
}


// MARK: - UIViewControllerPreviewingDelegate

    func previewingContext(previewingContext: UIViewControllerPreviewing, viewControllerForLocation location: CGPoint) -> UIViewController?
    {
        // Just Test View Controller
        return UIViewController(nibName: nil, bundle: nil)
    }

    func previewingContext(previewingContext: UIViewControllerPreviewing, commitViewController viewControllerToCommit: UIViewController)
    {
        self.presentViewController(viewControllerToCommit, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 4):

- Easy way to add 3D Touch in tableview cell. without one line of code

[image: storyboard image]

- More details : https://github.com/yudiz-solutions/YM3DTouch

Answer (score 1):

I noticed same issue.
I think the issue is caused by duplicated registration.
I added the flag then the issue is fixed.

Please try this(I'm using Objective-C, so please rewrite in swift).

Implement category that

```
@interface UITableViewCell (FourceTouchRegistered)

@property (nonatomic, assign) BOOL fourceTouchRegistered;

@end
```

and

```
#import "UITableViewCell+FourceTouchRegistered.h"
#import <objc/runtime.h>

@implementation UITableViewCell (FourceTouchRegistered)

- (void)setFourceTouchRegistered:(BOOL)fourceTouchRegistered
{
    objc_setAssociatedObject(self, @"fourceTouchRegistered", @(fourceTouchRegistered), OBJC_ASSOCIATION_ASSIGN);
}

- (BOOL)fourceTouchRegistered
{
    return [objc_getAssociatedObject(self, @"fourceTouchRegistered") boolValue];
}

@end
```

then

```
    if(cell.fourceTouchRegistered == NO) {
        cell.fourceTouchRegistered = YES;
        if (self.traitCollection.forceTouchCapability == UIForceTouchCapabilityAvailable) {
            [self registerForPreviewingWithDelegate:self sourceView:cell];
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to check if your preview UIViewController is already presented in your `previewingContext(_:viewControllerForLocation:)` method.

Something like

```
func previewingContext(previewingContext: UIViewControllerPreviewing, viewControllerForLocation location: CGPoint) -> UIViewController?
{
    if self.navigationController.presentedViewController.isKindOfClass(PreviewViewController) {
        return nil
    }
    return PreviewViewController()
}
```